# Mustache.js in PHP keep tags that could not be rendered?

Tags: mustache, mustache.php

I got the following:

```
{{#lang}}Dear{{/lang}} {{customer.ship_firstname}},<br />
{{#lang}}Thank you for ordering from{{/lang}} <a href="{{shop.URL}}">{{shop.name}}</a>.
```

Now i run render this with these settings:

```
$m = new Mustache_Engine(
                        array(
                        'helpers' => array(
                            'lang' => function($text) {
                                return __($text); // i18n translation
                            }),
                        'charset' => 'UTF-8'
                        )
                    );
$data = array();
echo $m->render($input, $data);
```

This outputs:

```
Dear ,<br />
Thank you for ordering from <a href=""></a>.
```

I would like to keep the tags that could not be rendered. So as above, when $data doesnt have data for `customer.ship_firstname` and `shop.URL`, the rendered data should still have the `{{customer.ship_firstname}}.`

Is there any mustache setting for disable/enable this?

Output i would want is the following:

```
Dear {{customer.ship_firstname}},<br />
Thank you for ordering from <a href="{{shop.URL}}">{{shop.name}}</a>.
```

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is no, that's not possible, for lots of really good reasons.

The longer answer is that you're asking the wrong question ;)

It's called [the XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378). Rather than asking "Is it possible to Y?", you would probably be better off asking "I'd like to accomplish X. I tried Y and that doesn't seem to work. How can I accomplish X?"

So, I'm assuming you meant to ask "I'd like to render only some tags in a Mustache template, for example, in Mustache.php on the server, so that I can render ther rest later, for example in Mustache.js in the browser. I tried rendering it with partial data, but it didn't keep the unrendered tags. How can I partially render a Mustache template?"

Your best bet is probably to use [Set Delimiter tags](http://mustache.github.io/mustache.5.html#Set-Delimiter) to render your template with two explicit sets of tags. It'd look something like this:

```
{{=[[ ]]=}}
[[# lang ]]Dear[[/ lang ]] {{ customer.ship_firstname }},<br />
[[# lang ]]Thank you for ordering from[[/ lang ]] <a href="{{ shop.URL }}">{{ shop.name }}</a>.
```

Then, on the first pass, it'd replace all the `[[ ]]` tags, leaving you with:

```
Dear {{ customer.ship_firstname }},<br />
Thank you for ordering from <a href="{{ shop.URL }}">{{ shop.name }}</a>.
```

Note that if you do two-pass rendering, you must be absolutely sure you trust the output of your first pass. If you're putting user data in there, it's entirely possible for them to use a "mustache injection" attack and do nefarious things. In your case, it looks like the data is coming from translation strings, so you're probably okay, but this note is also for everyone else doing the same thing.